# fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I am failing to send form contents to email. I am getting the following error:

```
: Warning
Message: fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:Name or service not known

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1986

Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.123mailsetup.com:25   (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known)

Filename: libraries/Email.php

   Line Number: 1986
```

My line 1986 is

```
$this->smtp_timeout);
```

**Part of the code in my controller**

```
$config = Array(
'protocol' => 'smtp',
'smtp_host' => 'smtp.xxxx.com',
'smtp_port' => 465,
'smtp_user' => 'xxxxx@xxx.com',
'smtp_pass' => 'xxxxxxxx',
'mailtype'  => 'html', 
'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);
                $this->load->library('email', $config);
                $this->email->from('xxxxx@xxx.com', 'Mailsetup');
                $this->email->to($email); 

                $this->email->subject('Domain transfer');
                $this->email->message( '<html><body>Domain to be transfered        '.$domain.' <br> Domain owner '.$name.' , <br> email '.$email.'

                </body></html>' );   

                $this->email->send();
```

Comment: You can use the IP for hostnames if they don't resolve via DNS. Note, trying to ping smtp.123mailsetup.com shows it does not resolve, but 123mailsetup.com does resolve to 77.235.54.121    Verify the name of the email server

Comment: Thanks man..that was the issue..managed to sort it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PHP Mailer  [See Here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

$auth = true;

if ($auth) {
  $mail->IsSMTP(); 
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
  $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; 
  $mail->Host = "smtp.xxxx.com"; 
  $mail->Port = 465; 
  $mail->Username = "username@host.com"; 
  $mail->Password = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
}

$mail->AddAddress("xxxxxxxx@xxxxxx.com");
$mail->SetFrom("JohnDeo@xxx.com", "John Deo");
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = "Test Email";
$mail->Body = "Hello World";

try {
  $mail->Send();
  return true;
} catch(Exception $e){
  echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Comment: and... the built in library of email under codeigniter just to be ignored directly?