# Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Connection timed out)

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

i am trying to send email using codeigniter email class but i am getting error Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Connection timed out)

```
public function index()
     {
     $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->view('sellerend/seller_signup.php');
       $config = array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'smtp_port' => '465',
        'smtp_user' => 'myemail@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => 'mypassword',
        'mailtype'  => 'html', 
        'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
        );

    $this->load->library('email',$config);
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from('myemail@gmail.com','my name');
    $this->email->to('ashurenu1993@gmail.com');
    $this->email->message('its working bro');
    if ($this->email->send())
    {
        echo "hi its works";
    }
    else
    {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to your gmail account and allow less secure apps under connected apps and sites

Change

```
 $this->load->library('email',$config)
 $this->email->initialize($config);
```

to

```
 $this->load->library('email');
 $this->email->initialize($config);
```

and

```
 'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
```

to

```
 'charset'   => 'utf-8'
```

Comment: i already allow less secure apps  but same error i am getting

Comment: Try out the changes above

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP Mailer and go to your Gmail account and allow the less secure app
[Example See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40002063/fsockopen-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-name-or-service-not-k/40006576#40006576)