# Contact us email sending is not working in codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

Hi i am having a request form in my website once i submit the details in request form not able to send an email to admin regarding the request.It is redirecting welcome/request function not getting any errors as well

Controller:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
function __construct() 
        { 
            parent::__construct();

    $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
    $this->load->library(array('session', 'form_validation', 'email'));
        }
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('index_model');
    $data['records2'] = $this->index_model->get_all_banners();
    $data['mainpage'] = "index";
    $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
}

function request()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<br /><span class="error"> ','</span>');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','First Name' , 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone','Mobile Number');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('description','Description');
        if($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE)   
        {   
        $data['mainpage']='index';
        $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
        }
    else
    {
        //get the form data
        $name = $this->input->post('name');
        $from_email = $this->input->post('email');
        $subject = $this->input->post('phone');
        $message = $this->input->post('description');       

        //set to_email id to which you want to receive mails
        $to_email = 'xxxxx@gmail.com';

        $config=Array(
    'protocol'=> 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com', //smtp host name
    'smtp_port' => '465', //smtp port number
    'smtp_user' => 'xxx@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' => '*******', //$from_email password
    'mailtype' =>'html',
    'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
    'wordwrap' => TRUE
    );

    //send mail
    $this->load->library('email',$config);
    $this->email->from($name);
    $this->email->to('$to_email');
    $this->email->subject($subj);
    $this->email->message($messagess1);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

        if ($this->email->send())
        {
            // mail sent
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Your mail has been sent successfully!</div>');
            redirect('welcome');
        }
        else
        {
            //error
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">There is error in sending mail! Please try again later</div>');
            redirect('welcome');
        }
    }
}


}
```

Comment: You have to find out the exact error, you can get it by below code
if ($this->email->send()) 
{
   Do your Stuff 
} else { 
  show_error($CI->email->print_debugger()); 
 die;
 }

Please let me know what error you get.

Comment: @vatsalshah not getting any error

Comment: @vatsalshah solved my problem updated answer as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download: [codeigniter-phpmailer](https://github.com/ivantcholakov/codeigniter-phpmailer)

```
public function send_mail_ctrl()
    { 

        $config['useragent']        = 'PHPMailer';              // Mail engine switcher: 'CodeIgniter' or 'PHPMailer'  
        $config['protocol']         = 'smtp';                   // 'mail', 'sendmail', or 'smtp'
        $config['mailpath']         = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
        $config['smtp_host']        = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $config['smtp_user']        = 'youremail';
        $config['smtp_pass']        = 'password';
        $config['smtp_port']        = 465;
        $config['smtp_timeout']     = 30;                       // (in seconds)
        $config['smtp_crypto']      = 'ssl';                    // '' or 'tls' or 'ssl'
        $config['smtp_debug']       = 0;                        // PHPMailer's SMTP debug info level: 0 = off, 1 = commands, 2 = commands and data, 3 = as 2 plus connection status, 4 = low level data output.
        $config['smtp_auto_tls']    = false;                    // Whether to enable TLS encryption automatically if a server supports it, even if `smtp_crypto` is not set to 'tls'.
        $config['smtp_conn_options'] = array();                 // SMTP connection options, an array passed to the function stream_context_create() when connecting via SMTP.
        $config['wordwrap']         = true;
        $config['wrapchars']        = 76;
        $config['mailtype']         = 'html';                   // 'text' or 'html'
        $config['charset']          = null;                     // 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-15', ...; NULL (preferable) means config_item('charset'), i.e. the character set of the site.
        $config['validate']         = true;
        $config['priority']         = 3;                        // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5; on PHPMailer useragent NULL is a possible option, it means that X-priority header is not set at all, see https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/449
        $config['crlf']             = "\n";                     // "\r\n" or "\n" or "\r"
        $config['newline']          = "\n";                     // "\r\n" or "\n" or "\r"
        $config['bcc_batch_mode']   = false;
        $config['bcc_batch_size']   = 200;
        $config['encoding']         = '8bit';

        $this->load->library('email');
         $this->email->initialize($config);
        /*$subject = 'This is a test';
        $message = '<p>This message has been sent for testing purposes.</p>';*/        

            $message = $this->input->post('message');
            $email = $this->input->post('email');
            $subject = $this->input->post('subject');


        // Get full html:
        $body = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=' . strtolower(config_item('charset')) . '" />
            <title>' . html_escape($subject) . '</title>
            <style type="text/css">
                body {
                    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                    font-size: 16px;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>

        ' . $message . '
        </body>
        </html>';
        // Also, for getting full html you may use the following internal method:
        //$body = $this->email->full_html($subject, $message);

        $result = $this->email
                ->from('your_email@gmail.com')
                ->reply_to('any_email@gmail.com')    // Optional, an account where a human being reads.
                ->to($email)
                ->subject($subject)
                ->message($body)
                ->send();

        var_dump($result);
        echo '<br />';
        //echo $this->email->print_debugger();

        if ($result == TRUE)
        {
            // mail sent
            echo "<div class='alert alert-success text-center'>Your mail has been sent successfully!</div>";
        }
        else
        {
           echo'<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Error in sending your message! Please try again later.</div>';
        }

        exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use PHP Mailer and Gmail as SMTP server and allow less secure app in gmail [See Code Example Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40002063/fsockopen-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-name-or-service-not-k/40006576#40006576)