# send email after registration

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

my controller code is

```
public function register()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('employer_name', 'Employer Name', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[30]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Usename Name', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[30]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email ID', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[employer_registration.email]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile', 'Mobile', 'trim|required|numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|matches[cpassword]|md5');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword', 'Confirm Password', 'trim|required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('employer/emp_register');
    }
    else
    {
     //insert the user registration details into database

 $data = array(
                'employer_name' => $this->input->post('employer_name'),
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'mobile' => $this->input->post('mobile'),
                'password' => $this->input->post('password')
            );
             $email = $this->input->post('email');
            $username = $this->input->post('username');
    if ($this->Employer_model->insertUser($data)){
                $this->load->library('email');
                $config_email['protocol'] = 'mail';
                $config_email['mailtype'] = 'html';
                $this->email->initialize($config_email);

                $this->email->from('test@domainname.com', 'domainname.com');
                $this->email->to($email);
                $this->email->subject('We welcome you');
                $this->email->message("Thanks for registration your username:$usernsme ");

                if ($this->email->send())
                {
                    echo "<script>alert('Email sent to $email mail id')</script>";
                } else {
                    $data['reg_status'] = "SOrry registration fail";
                }

                redirect('Employer/index');
}
else
        {
           echo "<script>alert('Oops! Error.  Please try again later!!!')</script>";
        }
    }

}
```

In my controller i validate all user details after that data inserting into data base , collect email and username into variable for sending mail purpose
I want to send email to user after successful registration, mail send to their registered email id.

```
function insertUser($data)
{
    return $this->db->insert('employer_registration', $data);
}
```

this is my simple model function

Comment: also send your models code will be easy to help.

Comment: `$this->email->send()` what is this doing then??

Comment: Can you explain more on your code like which error you are getting or what output you are getting after running code?

Comment: i am not getting any error, also not getting email on registered email id

Comment: after successful register thank you mail should be sent to email id

Comment: @Hikmat Sijapati in my model i simply insert data into data base

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: do you want to see my model code?

Comment: please check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40277048/6915353

Comment: before redirect('Employer/index'); line,  echo "output ".$data['reg_status']; exit; Also check what output you are getting from echo $this->email->print_debugger();
Check if you are getting something like "Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol:..."

Comment: after this line if ($this->Employer_model->insertUser($data)){ why there is a ' (inverted comma)

Answer (score 0):

Please add following code in your code and try :

```
$config_email['protocol']    = 'smtp';
$config_email[['smtp_host']    = 'smtp host name';
$config_email[['smtp_port']    = 'port';
$config_email[['smtp_timeout'] = 'timeout';     
$config_email[['smtp_user']    = 'your email account username';
$config_email[['smtp_pass']    = 'your email account password';
$config_email[['charset']    = 'utf-8';
$config_email[['newline']    = "\r\n";
$config_email[['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config_email[['validation'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: can you tell me, where should i put this in my code

Answer (score 0):

Above $this->email->initialize($config_email); in your code.

Thanks...