# Codeigniter unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googlemail.com error

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, ssl

PHP:

```
$config = Array(
  'useragent' => 'CodeIgniter',
  'mailpath' => '/usr/bin/sendmail',
  'protocol' => 'smtp',
  'smtp_host' => 'mail.kakaproperty.com',
  'smtp_port' => 587,
  'smtp_user' => 'info@kakaproperty.com', 
  'smtp_pass' => '******', 
  'mailtype' => 'html',
  'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
  'wordwrap' => TRUE
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->set_mailtype("html");
$this->email->from('info@kakaproperty.com'); // change it to yours
$this->email->to($data['email']);// change it to yours
$this->email->subject('Welcome to kaka property');
$this->email->message("New message by kaka property");
if($this->email->send())
{
    echo 1;
}
else
{
    $this->email->print_debugger();
}
```

Anyone can please help me why it displaying error unable to connect ssl://smtp.googlemail.com I am using kakaproperty.com as host why it happening.I removed email.php from config folder.

Comment: Scratch my previous comment, don't use `465` as port

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos I tried 465 but it not working.

Comment: Are you sure the credentials are right? i don't know if `stmp_user` seems right..

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos sir all information is correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending email with gmail smtp with codeigniter email library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555145/sending-email-with-gmail-smtp-with-codeigniter-email-library)

Comment: Check this and let me know if it works for you. :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40002063/fsockopen-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-name-or-service-not-k/40006576#40006576

Answer (score 0):

First You should check if any configuration for email is written as external files in codeigniter.if yes check the configuraions otherwise see below.

Some times you don't want to write server configurations manually in Codeigniter code when hosting server and email server are same  .You can directly send emails by following

```
$this->load->library('email');

$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config'charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->from('xx@xx.xx', 'xxx');
$this->email->to('yy@yy.yy');
$this->email->subject('xxxxx');
$this->email->message('xxx xxx xxx  xxx');

if ( ! $this->email->send()) 
       echo "Error";
} else {
    echo "Done";
}
```

Otherwise if you are using ssl://smtp.gmail.com .You can use below code

```
$this->load->library('email');

$config['protocol']    = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host']    = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
$config['smtp_port']    = '465';
$config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';
$config['smtp_user']    = 'xx@xx.xx';
$config['smtp_pass']    = '*****';

$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->from('xx@xx.xx', 'xxx');
$this->email->to('yy@yy.yy');
$this->email->subject('xxxxx');
$this->email->message('xxx xxx xxx  xxx');

if ( ! $this->email->send()) {
   echo "Error";
} else {
   echo "Done";
}
```

If you get fsockopen() error try with  'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',