# codeigniter fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting the following error message.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service` not known

Filename: `libraries/Email.php`

Line Number: 2055
searched here but the solution was to use `phpmailer`. but i want to use email library which is inbuilt in `codeigniter`.

Comment: Please add your code first and little more description regarding what you are trying to do?

Comment: Please refer  [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40002063/fsockopen-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-name-or-service-not-k/40006576 ]